# Twilio reply to incoming sms by ivr call

Tags: java, sms, twilio, twilio-api, ivr

I have just found out about Twilio so I don't know much about it what is possible or not. What I want to do is whenever a user sends an SMS to Twilio number I want to reply with an IVR (Interactive voice response). I have been able to reply to the incoming SMS with an SMS but not able to find how to reply with an IVR call. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a product like [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio) to do this with very little to no code. You associate a [Studio flow](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio) to your Twilio number (which becomes your source of Twilio Markup Language / TwiML) and can handle both inbound messages and inbound/outbound voice calls via the [Trigger Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/trigger-start) which initiates the Studio flow (a top down run through your logic composed of widgets).

You can send an inbound SMS which can be responded to with a [Send Message Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-message) for an SMS response and then a [Make Outgoing Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/make-outgoing-call) to connect that party to your IVR, also created in Studio using the [Gather Input on Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call).

[Twilio Studio You Tube Play List](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqrz4nXepkz5OwmqMONVJGBBa7grym6jx)

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely look into it.